# Parallel for loop in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, vectorization

I have data.frame **sent** with sentences in **sent$words** and dictionary with pos/neg words in **wordsDF** data frame (wordsDF[x,1]). Positive words = 1 and negative = -1 (wordsDF[x,2]). The words in that wordsDF data frame are sorted in decreasing order according to their length (length of string). I used this purpose for my following function.

How this function works:

1) Count occurancies of words stored in wordsDF through each sentences
2) Compute sentiment score: count of occurencies particular word (wordsDF) in particular sentence * sentiment value for that word (positive = 1, negative = -1)
3) Remove that matched word from sentence for another iteration.

Original solution using of **stringr** package:

```
scoreSentence_01 <- function(sentence){
  score <- 0
  for(x in 1:nrow(wordsDF)){
    count <- str_count(sentence, wordsDF[x,1])
    score <- (score + (count * wordsDF[x,2])) # compute score (count * sentValue)
    sentence <- str_replace_all(sentence, wordsDF[x,1], " ")
  }
  score
}
```

Faster solution - rows 4 and 5 replace row 4 in original solution.

```
scoreSentence_02 <- function(sentence){
  score <- 0
  for(x in 1:nrow(wordsDF)){
    sd <- function(text) {stri_count(text, regex=wordsDF[x,1])}
    results <- sapply(sentence, sd, USE.NAMES=F)
    score <- (score + (results * wordsDF[x,2])) # compute score (count * sentValue)
    sentence <- str_replace_all(sentence, wordsDF[x,1], " ")
  }
  score
}
```

Calling functions is:

```
scoreSentence_Score <- scoreSentence_01(sent$words)
```

In real I'm using data set with 300.000 sentences and dictionary with positive and negative words - overall 7.000 words. This approach is very very slow for that and because my beginer knowledge in R programming I'm in the end of my efforts.

Could you anyone help me, how to rewrite this function into vectorized or parallel solution, please. Any help or advice is very appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Dummy data:

```
sent <- data.frame(words = c("great just great right size and i love this notebook", "benefits great laptop at the top",
                         "wouldnt bad notebook and very good", "very good quality", "bad orgtop but great",
                         "great improvement for that great improvement bad product but overall is not good", "notebook is not good but i love batterytop"), user = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
                          stringsAsFactors=F)

posWords <- c("great","improvement","love","great improvement","very good","good","right","very","benefits",
          "extra","benefit","top","extraordinarily","extraordinary","super","benefits super","good","benefits great",
          "wouldnt bad")

negWords <- c("hate","bad","not good","horrible")

# Replicate original data.frame - big data simulation (700.000 rows of sentences)
df.expanded <- as.data.frame(replicate(10000,sent$words))
sent <- coredata(sent)[rep(seq(nrow(sent)),10000),]
sent$words <- paste(c(""), sent$words, c(""), collapse = NULL)
rownames(sent) <- NULL

# Ordering words in pos/negWords
wordsDF <- data.frame(words = posWords, value = 1,stringsAsFactors=F)
wordsDF <- rbind(wordsDF,data.frame(words = negWords, value = -1))
wordsDF$lengths <- unlist(lapply(wordsDF$words, nchar))
wordsDF <- wordsDF[order(-wordsDF[,3]),]
wordsDF$words <- paste(c(""), wordsDF$words, c(""), collapse = NULL)
rownames(wordsDF) <- NULL
```

Desired output is:

```
                                                                        words user scoreSentence_Score
                         great just great right size and i love this notebook    1                   4
                                             benefits great laptop at the top    2                   2
                                           wouldnt bad notebook and very good    3                   2
                                                            very good quality    4                   1
                                                         bad orgtop but great    5                   0
 great improvement for that great improvement bad product but overall is not good    6                   0
                                   notebook is not good but i love batterytop    7                   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now that I know you have to work around phrases and words... here's another shot at it. Basically, you have to split out your phrases first, score them, remove them from the string, then score your words...

```
library(stringr)
sent <- data.frame(words = c("great just great right size and i love this notebook", "benefits great laptop at the top",
                             "wouldnt bad notebook and very good", "very good quality", "bad orgtop but great",
                             "great improvement for that great improvement bad product but overall is not good", "notebook is not good but i love batterytop"), user = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
                   stringsAsFactors=F)

posWords <- c("great","improvement","love","great improvement","very good","good","right","very","benefits",
              "extra","benefit","top","extraordinarily","extraordinary","super","benefits super","good","benefits great",
              "wouldnt bad")

negWords <- c("hate","bad","not good","horrible")
sent$words2 <- sent$words
# split bad into words and phrases...
bad_phrases <- negWords[grepl(" ", negWords)]
bad_words <- negWords[!negWords %in% bad_phrases]
bad_words <- paste0("\\b", bad_words, "\\b")
pos_phrases <- posWords[grepl(" ", posWords)]
pos_words <- posWords[!posWords %in% pos_phrases]
pos_words <- paste0("\\b", pos_words, "\\b")
score <-  - str_count(sent$words2, paste(bad_phrases, collapse="|"))
sent$words2 <- gsub(paste(bad_phrases, collapse="|"), "", sent$words2)
score <- score + str_count(sent$words2, paste(pos_phrases, collapse="|"))
sent$words2 <- gsub(paste(pos_phrases, collapse="|"), "", sent$words2)
score <- score + str_count(sent$words2, paste(pos_words, collapse="|"))  - str_count(sent$words2, paste(bad_words, collapse="|")) 
score
```

Comment: I added my original task with some dummy data. If I use your approach so unfortunately is doesn't have desired output.

Comment: With minor changes, it matches your desired output. Regardless, this is the sort of approach your should use... vectorized code instead of loops. You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Many thanks Cory... Great and quick approach, you save me a lot of time.

Comment: Many thanks again for your great solution, but if I run it with my huge dictionaries it resulted into this error message:
Error: assertion 'tree->num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file 'tre-compile.c', line 634

Comment: Issue is on this line:
score <- score + str_count(sent$words2, paste(pos_words, collapse="|"))  - str_count(sent$words2, paste(bad_words, collapse="|"))

Comment: Do you happen to know, whats going on and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

can't you just do:

```
library("stringr")
scoreSentence_Score <- str_count(sent$words, wordsDF[,1]) - str_count(sent$words, wordsDF[,2])
```

Comment: The same or very similar approach is in my loops above. And trying to find out some faster solution, how to avoid for loop...

Comment: The solution I posted is vectorized, there is no loop.

Comment: Then you need to remove matched word from sentence, because you could have some duplicates: eg. you can have "great improvement" in sentence and if you have in wordsDF words: c("great improvement","great","improvement") so if you skip removing matched word in dictionary with word in sentence, you could have a duplicities...

Comment: So wordsDF contains not only words, but phrases as well? Remove the phrases. Get it down to just words...

Comment: Yes, exactly. I used that approach because I need exact match with pos/neg words and phrases.

Comment: If I do that, so in case of "product is not good" the sentiment score will be 0, because of "not" (-1) and "good" (+1). So I need phrases in my dictionary.